# Slow server performance on ecommerce website

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel

I have an ecommerece website with over a million products. Its running on debian 7, with apache2.2 , php5.4 , mysql 5.5 and laravel 4.1. It used to run smoothly, but lately it has become very slow.

I think It's because of amount of mysql queries to the server. I've used various mysql tools and found that that queries per second is very high (1000-2000). Although when im logging requests to the site and queries made It isn't nearly as much.

Also I haven't made much changes lately to the code and since it used to run ok, im not sure if the amount of queries is the problem (not sure how much it was when everything was ok).

Im looking for any ideas how to debug or find out what's wrong. The amount of users on page hasn't changed. There are about the same amount of request. I have some caching in place. But since I've got so many product pages and most of the users visit different pages so cache has little effect there. Any ideas how to make a better cache for that many product pages?

Comment: Could there be some "slow queries" that might be an issue and could be optimized via restructuring or indexes?

Comment: You can find something intresting here about caching https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache

Comment: Turn on the "general log" for a few seconds.  You _may_ find that Laravel is adding a bunch of relatively unnecessary queries into the mix.

Comment: What kind of caching are you using?

Comment: Are you eager loading queries with Eloquent? If not, you can hugely improve performance.

Comment: I tried logging queries and I didn't see anything out of the order. Im using laravel's file caching. But since my server inode limit gets full quick im deleting cache every day. Eager loading doesn't seem to be the issue aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "Query cache" turned on?  It may be helping or it may be hurting.

How much RAM is available to MySQL (including what it is using)?  Let's see these for various checks:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

Set `long_query_time = 0.5` and

1. turn on the slow log
2. wait a day
3. summarize the slowlog using `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest` -- These sort by 'impact on system'.
4. Let's see the top 3 queries for discussion.  Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN ...`.

Comment: Yes I have query caching turned on, but like I said mostly different pages are requested and new queries made. Also I don't think it is a ram issue (application uses around 1gb of ram and rest (out of 8) is used for cache.

Comment: I also logged slow queries. The most impact on system was on query: Count: 88  Time=3.52s (309s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=15.5 (1361)
  select * from `products` where `active` = 'S' and `category_id` in ('S') and `format_id` = 'S' limit N offset N. Where there are various number of category_ids. EXPLAIN: Result is too many rows(~700000). But isn't limit and offset for that?

Comment: That query needs `INDEX(active, format_id, category_id)` with `category_id` specifically third.

Comment: A query has to skip over `OFFSET` rows; there is no short-circuit for this (other than "remembering where you left off").  How about opening another question to discuss optimizing that one query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there were changes in ratio of insert/update/delete vs selects on your site. It's usual problem when your system is configured for fast data retrieval. But at some point you increase number of insert/update/delete and all system performance sags.

Of course it can be just increasing the users on the site through good content or something else. So, you need to compare current database load and load at the previous period without such problems.